# Inheritance in Javascript, What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-languages

Hi I am very new to javascript. i have been given the task to create a javascript framework to load multiple e-learning module and make them interact with each other via xml.

I am using a method of inheritance as shown below.

Base class EventDispatcher:

```
(function (window) {
    var EventDispatcher = function () {
            this._listeners = [];
        }
    var p = EventDispatcher.prototype;
    p._listeners = [];
    p.addListener = function (type, listener, scope) {
        scope = (typeof scope !== "undefined") ? scope : this;
        if (typeof this._listeners[type] == "undefined") {
            this._listeners[type] = [];
        }
        this._listeners[type].push({
            listener: listener,
            scope: scope
        });
    }
    p.removeListener = function (type, listener) {
        if (this._listeners[type] instanceof Array) {
            var listeners = this._listeners[type];
            for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (listeners[i].listener === listener) {
                    listeners.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    p.dispatchEvent = function (event) {
        if (typeof event == "string") {
            event = {
                type: event
            };
        }
        if (!event.target) {
            event.target = this;
        }
        if (!event.type) {
            throw new Error("Event object missing 'type' property.");
        }
        if (this._listeners[event.type] instanceof Array) {
            var listeners = this._listeners[event.type];
            for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length; i < len; i++) {
                listeners[i].listener.call(listeners[i].scope, event);
            }
        }
    }
    window.EventDispatcher = EventDispatcher;
}(window));
```

The Sub XMLLoader class that inherits EventDispatcher:

```
(function (window) {
    var XMLLoader = function () {}
    var p = XMLLoader.prototype = new EventDispatcher();
    p.xmlhttp = null;
    p.loadXML = function (url) {
        if (this.xmlhttp == null) {
            this.initXMLHttpRequest();
        }
        this.xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        this.xmlhttp.send();
    }
    p.initXMLHttpRequest = function () {
        var currObj = this;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var xmlLoaderEvent = null;
            if (currObj.xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && currObj.xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                xmlLoaderEvent = new XMLLoaderEvents();
                xmlLoaderEvent.type = XMLLoaderEvents.XML_DOC_SUCCESS;
                xmlLoaderEvent.data = {
                    xmlDoc: currObj.xmlhttp.responseXML,
                    xmlString: currObj.xmlhttp.responseText
                };
            } else if (currObj.xmlhttp.status == 404) {
                xmlLoaderEvent = new XMLLoaderEvents();
                xmlLoaderEvent.type = XMLLoaderEvents.XML_DOC_ERROR;
            }
            if (xmlLoaderEvent != null) {
                currObj.dispatchEvent(xmlLoaderEvent);
            }
        };
    }
    /*p.onReadyStateChange = function()
    {
        var xmlLoaderEvent = null;
        if(this.xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && this.xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            xmlLoaderEvent = new XMLLoaderEvents();
            xmlLoaderEvent.type = XMLLoaderEvents.XML_DOC_SUCCESS;
            xmlLoaderEvent.data = this.xmlhttp.responseXML;
        }
        else if(this.xmlhttp.status == 404)
        {
            xmlLoaderEvent = new XMLLoaderEvents();
            xmlLoaderEvent.type = XMLLoaderEvents.XML_DOC_ERROR;
        }

        if (xmlLoaderEvent != null)
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(xmlLoaderEvent);
        }
    }*/
    window.XMLLoader = XMLLoader;
}(window));
```

Now I am calling the xmlLoader multiple times in another class. Before calling it everytime I create a new instance using `new XMLLoader();`. My understanding was that this should create a new instance and `this._listeners` in the base class should be `[]` empty. But that is not happening. Please help me and tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript object members that are prototyped as arrays become shared by all class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla)

Comment: Thanks Felix the post is definitely not duplicate but the problem is. It cleared some of my doubts as to whats happening in my code.

Comment: I thought this is what the problem was all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class inheritance doesn't work as usual when simulated in javascript. For example, there is no implicit superclass constructor calling.

You don't call the "mother class" construtor in your "subclass constructor". That's why "Mother class" fields are not initialized.

Instead of

```
var XMLLoader = function () {}
```

what you should write is

```
var XMLLoader = function () {
    EventDispatcher.apply(this, arguments); /* this is a common way to execute
       the code of the "mother class" "constructor" with the same "this" */
}
```

Comment: thanks sam i thought " var p = XMLLoader.prototype = new EventDispatcher();" initialize EventDispatcher. I have achieved my goal by inserting "this._listener = []" in the XMLLoader constructor. But i really want to know what exactly is happening here.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the prototype chain and OOP in javascript, you could read the two following articles: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/ http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm I also recommend reading this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do (it's not long, and it will help you a lot if you are to write a lot of javascript). Javascript is an atypical language and you can loose a lot of time if you don't do things right.