# Inheritance And ExtJs using extend

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to setup a base class and derived class with ExtJS using `Ext.extend`.

**:Base Class:**

```
var Base = Ext.extend(Object, {
    settings: {},
    constructor: function(args) {
        var baseArgs = { 'user': '', 'password': '' };
        Ext.apply(this.settings, args, baseArgs);
    }
});
```

**:Derived Class:**

```
var Derived = Ext.extend(Base, {
    constructor: function(args) {
        Derived.superclass.constructor.call(this, args);
    }
});
```

**:Problem:**

```
var test1 = new Derived({ 'user': 'blackey1', 'password': 'blackeypw1' });
var test2 = new Derived({ 'user': 'blackey2', 'password': 'blackeypw2' });
```

At this point `test1.settings` is equivalent to `test2.settings` (using `blackey2` and `blackeypw2`) as if they are pointing to the same object, I'm looking to find how to create independent objects.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your current code, the empty `settings` object is added to the prototype of `Base`, so that one `settings` object is shared by all instances of `Base` and any instances of classes derived from `Base` (like `Derived`).  What you should do instead is create the empty `settings` object in `Base`'s `constructor` function so that each instance gets its own `settings` object:

```
var Base = Ext.extend(Object, {
    constructor: function(args) {
        var baseArgs = { 'user': '', 'password': '' };
        this.settings = {};
        Ext.apply(this.settings, args, baseArgs);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please clarify the logic behind why the same instance of settings object is shared by all instances of Base, and Derived classes? This totally got me by surprise. One would normally expect that each Derived object would get it's own instance of settings.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's because of JavaScript's prototypal inheritance. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla).