# javascript prototype inheritance - shared property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have saved a property `_data` in prototype as a definition for all created objects.

```
 function A() {}
 A.prototype._data = [];
```

Now all objects created from `A` have property `_data`.

I'd like prototype inheritance, where `_data` of prototype will have `_data` values from all prototypes in prototype chain.

Don't know direct way, in this example I use a getter `get()`.

```
 function A() {}

 A.prototype._data = [];

 A.prototype.add = function(rec) {
   this.__proto__._data.push(rec);
 }

 A.prototype.get = function() {
   if(typeof this.__proto__.constructor.prototype.get == 'function')
   {
     return this.__proto__.constructor.prototype.get().concat(this.__proto__._data);
   }
   else
   {
     return this.__proto__._data || [];
   }
 }

 function B() {}
 B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, { constructor: { value: B }});
 B.prototype._data = [];
```

When I create object `a` with values `aa` and object `b` with value `bb`, `b.get()` returns `[aa, bb]`. And later if `_data` of prototype `A` will be extended with `aaaa`, function `b.get()` returns `[aa, aaaa, bb]`.

```
 var a = new A(), b = new B();

 a.add('aa');
 b.add('bb');
 console.log(b.get()); // [aa, bb]

 a.add('aaaa');
 console.log(b.get()); // [aa, aaaa, bb]

 // EDITED - _data in A prototype shoud be without B
 console.log(a.get()); // [aa, aaaa]
```

Is it a good (standard) way how to achieve this? I mean using constructor correction while `Object.create` and reference parent prototype with `constructor.prototype`?

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j9fKP/

Reason for all of this is field definition for scheme in ORM library, where inheritance of schemes is allowed. Child scheme has to have all fields from parent scheme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript object members that are prototyped as arrays become shared by all class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like prototype inheritance, where `_data` of prototype will have `_data` values from all prototypes in prototype chain.

That's a different thing. "Prototype inheritance" means that if there's a `_data` property on the current object, it won't go looking further in the chain. Also, it seems to be a kind of [issue with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects), though I'm not sure what you really want. However, it hardly will make sense to let an array object inherit from another array, if you actually want to concatenate them.

So I think your getter is really fine.

> Is it a good (standard) way how to achieve this? I mean using constructor correction while Object.create and reference parent prototype with constructor.prototype

Constructor correction is nice, but [actually quite useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622137/what-is-the-constructor-property-really-used-for) (especially if you expect a standard-conform `Object.create`).

However, in `this.__proto__.constructor.prototype` either the `.__proto__` or the `.constructor.prototype` is redundant. Since both are either nonstandard or *require* constructor correction, you should use the standard [`Object.getPrototypeOf()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get your prototype object.

With the following very generic solution, you can nest the inheritance (A.proto, B-proto, B-instance, …) arbitrarily deep. Everything inheriting from `A.prototype` will have an `add` method which adds `_data` to the current object, and a `get` method that traverses the prototype chain and collects all `_data`:

```
function A() {
    // this._data = []; // why not?
}
A.prototype._data = []; // not even explicitly needed
A.prototype.add = function(rec) {
    if (! this.hasOwnProperty("_data")) // add it to _this_ object
        this._data = [];
    this._data.push(rec);
}
A.prototype.addToAllInstances = function(rec) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).add(rec);
}
A.prototype.get = function() {
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    var base = typeof proto.get == 'function' ? proto.get() : [];
    // maybe better:
    // var base = typeof proto.get == 'function' && Array.isArray(base = proto.get()) ? base : [];
    if (this.hasOwnProperty("_data"))
        return base.concat(this._data); // always get a copy
    else
        return base;
}

function B() {
    A.call(this);
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, { constructor: { value: B }});
B.prototype._data = []; // not even explicitly needed
```

Example usage:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();

a.add('ai');
a.get(); // [ai]

a.addToAllInstances('ap'); // === A.prototype.add('ap');
a.get(); // [ap, ai]
new A().get(); // [ap]
b.get(); // [ap]
b.prototype.get(); // [ap]

b.add('bi');
b.get(); // [ap, bi]

a.addToAllInstances('aap');
b.addToAllInstances('bp');
b.get(); // [ap, aap, bp, bi]
```

Comment: Really nice code! with getPrototypeOf and also forgotten instance _data property. Thank you a lot for excellent explanation and example.  Exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function A() {}
     A.prototype._data = [];

 A.prototype.add = function(rec) {
   this._data.push(rec);
 }

 A.prototype.get = function() {
   return this._data;
 }

 function B() {}
 B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, { constructor: { value: B    }});

 B.prototype._data = [];

 B.prototype.get = function() {
   return A.prototype._data.concat(this._data);
 }  

 a.add('aa');
 b.add('bb');
 console.log(b.get()); // [aa, bb]

 a.add('aaaa');
 console.log(b.get()); // [aa, aaaa, bb]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPcUz/)

Comment: i'm sorry for bad question i edited lately, a.get() should return only [aa, aaaa]. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a better understanding of what you want to do now, so I've deleted my earlier answer and am posting this one.

Here's how I think I'd do it (with the caveat that I'm not at all sure that with an *even better* understanding, a completely different approach wouldn't be better):

```
function A() {}
A.prototype._Adata = [];

A.prototype.add = function(rec) {
  this._Adata.push(rec);
};

A.prototype.get = function() {
  return this._Adata;
};

function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, { constructor: { value: B }});

B.prototype._Bdata = [];

B.prototype.add = function(rec) {
  this._Bdata.push(rec);
};
B.prototype.get = function() {
  return this._Adata.concat(this._Bdata);
  // Or: return A.prototype.get.call(this).concat(this._Bdata);
};

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

a.add('aa');
b.add('bb');
console.log(b.get()); // [aa, bb]

a.add('aaaa');
console.log(b.get()); // [aa, aaaa, bb]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPcUz/1/)

That way, `B` isn't reaching too deeply into `A`'s internals.

Comment: Isn't `_Adata` an "A internal"? You could (and imo should) use A's `get`.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I guess you could argue that it is. To me, the whole point of these is to share that information, so I don't consider them "internal", and calling `A`'s version of `get` is a pain without a helper library. But I've added it as an option.