# javascript delete item from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have an js object

```
var myClass = Class.extend({
    _innerArr: [],
    add: function( id, url ){
        this._innerArr.push([id, url]);
    },
    delete: function( id ){
        $( this._innerArr ).each(function( index ){
            if ( $( this )[0]==id ){
                 this._innerArr.splice( index, 1); // Doesn't work!!! Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'splice' of undefined 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But, if code change on:

```
 var globalArr;

 var myClass = Class.extend({
    _innerArr: [],
    add: function( id, url ){
        this._innerArr.push([id, url]);
    },
    delete: function( id ){
        globalArr = this._innerArr;
        $( this._innerArr ).each(function( index ){
            if ( $( this )[0]==id ){
                 globalArr.splice( index, 1); // Work!!! 
            }
        });

    }
});
```

why this._innerArr not work? I don't want using adding variable in my project. Thinks, other way is...

Comment: Use a plain loop, not `each`

Comment: Moving the `var` into the `delete` function is enough, you don't need it completely global

Comment: [You've got a large problem with your `.innerArr`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449838/javascript-prototype-inheritance-shared-property)

Answer (score 3):

When using jQuery's `.each()` method, the function gets called with `this` as the current value of the array. You're using that when doing `$( this )[0]`. (`$( this )[0]` might be unnecessary btw.)

You don't need to create a global variable for this, but you might as well set a scoped variable in the `delete` function.

Alternately, you can just use a `for` loop instead of jQuery's `each()`. That's also a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because the scope of `this` changes inside of the `.each()` callback; this is a pretty well known phenomena and typically involves saving `this` in another variable outside of the function call.

Instead of splicing things yourself, you could make use of `jQuery.grep()`:

```
this._innerArr = $.grep(this._innerArr, function(element) {
    return element[0] != id;
});
```