# Issue with prototype inheritance in Javascript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I have two files: BaseController.js and EventRecordController.js.  EventRecord needs to inherit a few methods from BaseController.

**BaseController**

```
var Q = require('q'),
    util = require('../util');

exports.BaseController = function(req, res) {
    this.req = res;
    this.res = res;
    this.fields = {};
    this.error = {
        code: 200,
        message: 'BAD REQUEST: The parameters provided were invalid. See response body for error messages.',
        specific_message: ''
    };
};

// Utility method to handle returning errors that are thrown.
exports.BaseController.prototype.handle_errors = function(error) {
    if(this.error.code === 500) {
        util.internal_error(this.res, this.response_type);
    } else {
        var response = util.build_error_response(this.response_type, this.error.code, this.error.message, this.error.specific_message);
        util.send_response(this.res, this.response_type, this.error.code, response);
    }
};

// Check to see if a user is authenticated and whether they are using a correct response type.
exports.BaseController.prototype.validate_response_type_and_authenticate = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    util.validate_response_type_and_authenticate(this.req, this.res, function(auth_data, response_type) {

        this.auth_data = auth_data;
        this.company_user_uid = this.auth_data.data.company.uid;
        this.response_type = response_type;
        this.v3_token = this.auth_data.data.token;

        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

**EventRecordController**

```
var base_controller = require("./BaseController"),
    Q = require('q'),
    util = require('../util'),
    validator = require('validator');


exports.EventRecordController = function(req, res) {

    function EventRecord(req, res) {
        base_controller.BaseController.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Inherit from BaseController, then fix constructor.
    EventRecord.prototype = new base_controller.BaseController();
    EventRecord.prototype.constructor = EventRecord;

    EventRecord.run = function() {
        console.log(this.error);
    };

    return EventRecord;
};
```

When I run the following code, this.error logs as undefined from within the run() method.

```
var event_record_controller = require("./controllers/EventRecordController"),
    util = require('./util'),
    validator = require('validator');

exports.record = function(req, res) {
    var controller = new event_record_controller.EventRecordController(req, res);
    controller.run();
};
```

I think I'm missing something obvious here, but my experience with prototype based inheritance is limited.

Comment: If a constructor `return`s an object, the object created by `new` will be discarded. So, `new EventRecordController()` is returning the `function EventRecord` rather than an instance.

Comment: Did you want to use revealing module pattern for the `EventRecordController`? Then you're missing the IEFE call

Comment: Why is `run` not a function on the `EventRecord` prototype, but a "static" one?

Comment: You've got [issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla) because [you're doing the inheritance wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Comment: The callback to `util.validate_response_type_and_authenticate` is probably called with the wrong `this` either

Comment: `run` was "static" because I was experimenting.  It has since been reverted to a prototype.  @JonathanLonowski set me on the right course for getting this to work.  Thanks @Bergi for pointing out the wrong this in my `validate...` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.error` is `undefined` because `run` is being called directly on the constructor, which doesn't have an `error`, rather than one of its instances.

Methods that are attached directly to the constructor aren't inherited. For that, they should be attached to the `prototype`:

```
// "static" method available only through the constructor itself
EventRecord.run = function() {
    console.log(this.error);
};

// "class" method inherited by instances of `EventRecord`
EventRecord.prototype.run = function () {
    console.log(this.error);
};
```

---

But, you also don't yet have an instance of `EventRecord` to call `.run()` on.

When a constructor `return`s an object, the instance that was created by using `new` will be discarded. So, calling `new EventRecordController()` is just returning the `function EventRecord`.

```
var controller = new event_record_controller.EventRecordController(req, res);
console.log(typeof controller);     // function
console.log(controller.name);       // "EventRecord"

controller = new controller(req, res);
console.log(typeof controller);     // object
```

You could revise `EventRecordController` to `return` an instance of `EventRecord`:

```
// ...

return new EventRecord(req, res);
```

Though, you might consider consolidating the 2 constructors rather than having one generate the other:

```
exports.EventRecordController = function(req, res) {
    base_controller.BaseController.apply(this, arguments);
};

util.inherits(exports.EventRecordController, base_controller.BaseController);

exports.EventRecordController.prototype.run = function () {
    console.log(this.error);
};
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, and gave me a better understanding of how to use prototypal inheritance.  Thanks!