# Javascript class inheritance. Subclass changes main class's properties?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

```
var Main = function(){};
    Main.prototype = {
        'times' : 0,
        'request': function(){},
        ...
    };

var SubA = function(){};
    SubA.prototype = new Main() // same with Object.create(Main.prototype);
    SubA.prototype.constructor = SubA;

var SubB = function(){};
    SubB.prototype = new Main() // same with Object.create(Main.prototype);
    SubB.prototype.constructor = SubB;
```

Now:

```
var sub_a = new SubA();
    sub_a.times = 1;

var sub_b = new SubB();
   // Here sub_b.times is already 1, how?
```

When I change the properties of `sub` classes, properties of `Main` are also changing, shouldn't it stay at `0`?

Comment: It stays at 0 for me just using Chrome console?

Comment: `sub_a.times = 1;` will never (!) change the `sub_b.times`, unless `sub_a === sub_b`. This has nothing to do with prototypes. *Assigning* to a property always adds or changes the property on the objects itself (whether it exists in the prototype chain or not).

Comment: Related: [Javascript object members that are prototyped as arrays become shared by all class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4425318/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have already pointed out, your exact question is incorrect and, in fact, `sub_b.times` is still `0`. Perhaps something else is going on in your code.

I will take a guess as to what might be going on *outside of your specific question* and explain primitive vs. reference types through the code below. Notice the difference between storing `times` and `count` on our prototype:

```
var Main = function(){};
Main.prototype = {
  'times' : 0,
  'count': {value: 0}
};

var SubA = function(){};
  SubA.prototype = new Main();
  SubA.prototype.constructor = SubA;

var SubB = function(){};
  SubB.prototype = new Main();
  SubB.prototype.constructor = SubB;

var subA = new subA();
var subB = new subB();
```

Our `times` property is a primitive value and when we incrementing the primitive value of subA.times has no effect on subB and vice-versa:

```
console.log(subA.times); // 0
console.log(subB.times); // 0

subA.times = 1;
console.log(subA.times); // 1
console.log(subB.times); // 0

subB.times = 100;
console.log(subA.times); // 1
console.log(subB.times); // 100
```

Our `count` property, however, is an object storing a `value` primitive. An object is a reference type and, in short, means that `subA.count` and `subB.count` reference the same object in memory and if we change that object's properties it will be reflected in both. **If I had to take a guess, this is likely the case that might be happening in your actual implementation.**

```
console.log(subA.count.value); // 0
console.log(subB.count.value); // 0

subA.count.value = 1;
console.log(subA.count.value); // 1
console.log(subB.count.value); // 1

subB.count.value = 100;
console.log(subA.count.value); // 100
console.log(subB.count.value); // 100
```

One final note: If we decide to re-assign the `count` property of one of our instances to a new object then it will no longer reference the same object and would be separate:

```
subA.count = {value: -1}; // New object
console.log(subA.count.value); // -1 (new object value)
console.log(subB.count.value); // 100 (old value from above)

subB.count.value = 99;
console.log(subA.count.value); // -1
console.log(subB.count.value); // 99
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what was happening, I had an object with count & some other values.