# Javascript object references

Tags: javascript, reference

I'm trying to animate Objects in a Canvas with a function, so I wrote this object - which I'm trying to animate:

```
var chartElements = {
    'bottomLine': {
        'width': 0,
        setWidth: function (x) {
            this.width = x;
        },
        getWidth: function () {
            return this.width;
        },
    },
};
```

...and created it with: `var cE = Object.create(chartElements);`
So my, first thought was, to just change the var with `cE.chartElements.bottomLine.width = 10`, but this didn't work so I wrote a function where I can reference to the getters and setters:

```
function changeIt(val, getter, setter) {
    console.log(getter());
    setter(val);
    console.log(getter());
}
```

And now it's getting very, very weird because first, the `getter`-Function returnes an `undefined`, but after it's set, it always returnes the new variable but without changing the actual property of the `cE`-Object. So it seems like I'm creating a new Object somewhere.

So, whats wrong, why can't I change the actual property of `cE`?

Comment: Can you please post the code for `getter()` and `setter()`?

Comment: just use cE.bottomLine.setWidth(10); and console.log(cE.bottomLine.getWidth();

Comment: @imranqasim: That would be very bad if there will ever be more than one instance created via `Object.create(chartElements)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first problem is that you're trying to use a property on your object (`chartElements`) that doesn't exist. Instead of

```
cE.chartElements.bottomLine.width = 10
```

it would be

```
cE.bottomLine.width = 10;
```

or, of course, using the setter you created:

```
cE.bottomLine.setWidth(10);
```

***but***, that brings us to the second problem:

By doing

```
var cE = Object.create(chartElements);
```

...you're creating an object, referred to by `cE`, that uses `chartElements` as its underlying prototype. In memory, you get something that looks like this *(love me some ASCII-art)*:

```
                         +-------------+                                  
chartElements--------+-->|   (object)  |                                  
                     |   +-------------+      +----------+               
                     |   | bottomLine  |----->| (object) |               
                     |   +-------------+      +----------+               
                     |                        | width: 0 |               
      +-----------+  |                        | setWidth |---->(function)
cE--->| (object)  |  |                        | getWidth |---->(function)
      +-----------+  |                        +----------+               
      | __proto__ |--+
      +-----------+
```

That means that `cE.bottomLine` refers to the **prototype's** `bottomLine` property. If you change it, you'll be changing the `bottomLine` object of the prototype, which would mean if you have other objects you've created via `Object.create(chartElements)`, if they use `bottomLine`, they'll see the change (because they're all using the **same** `bottomLine`).

Instead, you might have a prototype for `bottomLine`:

```
var bottomLinePrototype = {
    width: 0,
    setWidth: function (x) {
        this.width = x;
    },
    getWidth: function () {
        return this.width;
    }
};
```

and a constructor function or builder function for your chart element creation:

Here's a constructor function:

```
// Constructor function
function ChartElement() {
    this.bottomLine = Object.create(bottomLinePrototype);
}

// use it via `new`
var cE = new ChartElement();
```

Here's a builder function:

```
// Builder function
function buildChartElement() {
    return {
        bottomLine: Object.create(bottomLinePrototype)
    };
}

// Use it *without* `new`
var cE = buildChartElement();
```

Now, your objects have their *own* `bottomLine` object:

```
      +-------------+      
cE--->|   (object)  |      
      +-------------+      +-----------+
      | bottomLine  |----->| (object)  |
      +-------------+      +-----------+     +----------+               
                           | __proto__ |---->| (object) |               
                           +-----------+     +----------+               
                                             | width: 0 |               
                                             | setWidth |---->(function)
                                             | getWidth |---->(function)
                                             +----------+
```

Initially that looks pretty similar, but the difference is that since the object has its own `bottomLine` object, you can safely use:

```
cE.bottomLine.width = 10;
```

or

```
cE.bottomLine.setWidth(10);
```

...to set that instance's `bottomLine`'s `width`, which will shadow the one on its prototype, giving us:

```
      +-------------+      
cE--->|   (object)  |      
      +-------------+      +-----------+
      | bottomLine  |----->| (object)  |
      +-------------+      +-----------+     +----------+               
                           | __proto__ |---->| (object) |               
                           | width: 10 |     +----------+               
                           +-----------+     | width: 0 |               
                                             | setWidth |---->(function)
                                             | getWidth |---->(function)
                                             +----------+
```

This works because prototype properties work differently when you're doing a **set** vs. **get** operation:

- When you're **getting**, if the object itself doesn't have the property, the JavaScript engine looks to the object's prototype to see if it has the property. If so, it uses the value of the prototype's property. If not, it looks to the prototype's *prototype*, and so on.
- When you're **setting**, though, it sets the value on the object itself, creating a new property on the object if necessary or upating the value of the property if it's already there. The prototype's property is unaffected.

Comment: Nice explanation of the problem :-) Should be linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects/) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla)