# How do I change an inherited array with an inherited method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance

I want to have an object that inherits an array property and a method to add elements to the *inherited array*. However, the inherited method `yChange()` changes the prototype array and not the inherited array. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla) explains why the undesired behavior happens. But can't figure out how to get the desired behavior.

```
var parent = {
    x: 0,
    y: [],
    xChange: function () {this.x += 1},
    yChange: function () {this.y.push(1)}
};

var child = Object.create(parent);
child.xChange();
child.yChange();

console.log(child.x, child.y); // 1 [1]
console.log(parent.x, parent.y); // 0 [1]
```

Desired:

```
console.log(child.x, child.y); // 1 [1]
console.log(parent.x, parent.y); // 0 []
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can’t use a constructor?

Comment: I could, but I'd like to use object literals and `Object.create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felix is right about an assignment being necessary to change child.y.  In your example, you could check to see if the memory addresses are the same first and then assign a new one for the new instance if they match.  Like so:

```
var parent = {
    x: 0,
    y: [],
    xChange: function () {this.x += 1},
    yChange: function () {
        if (this.y == Object.getPrototypeOf(this).y)
            this.y = new Array()
        this.y.push(1)
    }
};

var child = Object.create(parent);
child.xChange();
child.yChange();

console.log(child.x, child.y); // 1 [1]
console.log(parent.x, parent.y); // []
```

Comment: If one expects to be able to do `parent.yChange`, then the condition should be extended by `this !== parent && ...`

Comment: I think I'll just have to use a constructor. Thanks @JpajiRajnish.

Comment: I realized after writing this that you'd have a problem if you wanted to inherit from `child`.  To solve this you can call the prototype of the instance instead of `parent` explicitly and check the memory address of that. (answer is edited)

Answer (score 5):

> However, the inherited method yChange() changes the prototype array and not the inherited array.

There is no difference between the "inherited" array and the "prototype" array. They are one and the same.

You have to give `child` its own array:

```
var child = Object.create(parent);
child.y = [];
```

---

> So, I can't inherit an 'own' array as with the number? The question is how to do it with an inherited array.

Everything that is inherited is not "owned" by the child. Even numbers. The difference is that numbers are not mutable, hence the issue is not apparent.

Look closely what here:

```
this.x += 1
```

You are **assigning** a new value to `this.x`. This will create `child.x`, not modify `parent.x`.

Lets look at

```
this.y.push(1);
```

You are **not** assigning anything here. You are *reading* `this.y`, which resolves to `parent.y` and you are mutating the array object itself.

Is it clearer now why you have to **assign** a new array to `child.y` (`child.y = [];`) ? The assignment is what gives the child its own copy of the data.

The difference between the number and array case is that numbers are **immutable** and arrays are **mutable**. The immutability of numbers *forces* you to create a new number and *assign* it.

Not so with mutable values. You have to explicitly create a copy of the value if you don't want it to be shared (and that's what  `child.y = [];` is basically doing).

Comment: So, I can't inherit an 'own' array as with the number? The question is how to do it with an inherited array.

Comment: *Everything* that is inherited is **not** "owned" by the child. Even numbers. The difference is that numbers are *not mutable*, hence the issue is not apparent.

Comment: You might want to read the linked question again, I feel like you haven't really understood the *why* (ha, I answered that one... interesting, maybe I didn't do such a good job).

Comment: Yeah, my question is most definitely, "how?"

Comment: @Dave: Then the answer is: "you can't". You can't magically make a single array (`parent.y`) act like it was two.

Comment: I added some more information, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think you did a fine job… But yes I know the feeling of finding old answers of oneself :-)

Comment: `xChange: function () {this.x = this.x + 1}` yields the same results. Does that mean `this.x` refers to `parent.x` on the right side and `child.x` on the left?

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks Bergi :) (and for the improvements)

Comment: @Dave: Yes, at least the first time it is called. After that it will always refer to `child.x`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. I guess "inheritance" with object create is totally senseless to me.

Comment: @Dave: At least not if you need instance specific data, yeah. That's the problem that constructor functions solve. `new Foo()` is basically doing this (simplified): `var newObj = Object.create(Foo.prototype); Foo.apply(newObj, arguments); return newObj;`. And the `Foo.apply(...)` part is where all the instance specific initialization happens.