# How to change array of one instance

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

relevant parts of the code:

```
function myObj(wgtId, options, parentPage) {
    if (!wgtId) return;

    this.colors=['red','pink'];
    hmiWidget.call(this, wgtId, options, parentPage);
}

myObj.prototype = new hmiWidget();  // Inheriting the base class Widget

myObj.prototype.setValue = function (newValue) {
    var index = newValue;
    var color = this.colors[index];
    this.elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

$hmi.fn.myObj = function (options, parentPage) {
    return new myObj(this.wgtId, options, parentPage);
};
```

Usage:

```
  $(".myClass").myObj( {colors:['#ccccff','#000099']} );  // start with blue
  . . .
  objWidget.setValue(newVal);
```

All this works well.

Now I need to change the colors array for specific instance.

I tried to use -

```
objWidget.colors[0] = "#ccffcc";
```

but it affected all instances. (I do not understand why all instances are affected.)

from [Javascript object members that are prototyped as arrays become shared by all class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425318/javascript-object-members-that-are-prototyped-as-arrays-become-shared-by-all-cla) 
I understand that I cannot add and use

```
code:
myObj.prototype.setColor = function (index, newColor) {
    this.colors[index] = newColor;
}
usage:
objWidget.setColor(0, "#009900");
```

because 'prototype' will share my colors array between all instances.

so how can I affect colors array of only one instance?

Comment: Where are you creating objWidget? Are you using the new keyword?

Comment: It seems like every instance already has its own `color` array, so you should not have any problems. Please create a runnable example.

Comment: $(".myClass").myObj( {colors:['#ccccff','#000099']} ); // I do not use new keyword.

Comment: Then what exactly is `return new myObj(...);`? ;) looks like `new` to me.

Comment: ok. The library do use 'new'.

Comment: Can you show the code of `hmiWidget`? Notice that [you're doing inheritance wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572)

Comment: its a large library containing some files, I cannot load a simple example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally I by-passed the problem by using simple variables col0, col1 instead of using the array.

not optimal but solved my current needs. :(

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are using the same instance for each object, that's why changing color value, it get changed everywhere. Try creating new instance for each .myClass

```
$hmi.fn.myObj = function (options, parentPage) {
    return this.each(function(){
        (new myObj(this.wgtId, options, parentPage));           
    });
};
```

Tell me if you need more help.

Comment: tried it. but it did not help. (need to add ')' at the end of line 3 in the proposed code ).