# Javascript ES6 shared class variable

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) {
        // ...

        this._some_obj = new SomeObj({
            param1: arg1,
            param2: arg2
        });
    }

    // ...
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

Now I want to do the same thing but with `_some_obj` shared between all instances of the class.

After searching around I'm unclear as to the correct way to do this in ES6.

Comment: well.. how would you do it in es5?

Comment: If it's shared between all instances, what is the expected behavior for the arguments? Would the first call initialize it with whatever the first args happen to be?

Comment: @loganfsmyth - Yes I hadn't really thought this through in that regard. I assume there should be some type of initialization function instead of putting those args in the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

As known from ES5, you can just put it on the class's prototype object:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) {
        …
    }
    …
}
Foo.prototype._some_obj = new SomeObj({
    param1: val1,
    param2: val2
});
```

Or directly on `Foo`, if you don't need to access it as a property on instances.

Comment: I read that defining properties on the prototype is a bad idea and that this is why it wasn't included in ES6 classes in the first place. Is that not true?

Comment: @SeanLynch it's not a good diea to REdefine prototype properties on classes you didn't make. For instance, `Math.prototype.min = ` is not a good property to overwrite, because it effects every instance of `Math.min`

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I see. I didn't really understand that. Thank you!

Comment: adding to classes you own isn't the same as adding to native objects prototypes (which can seriously mess with any libraries you may use)

Comment: In this case, how would I get the values of `arg1` and `arg2` to be available to the constructor of SomeObj. I think `Foo.prototype._some_obj` would be created before the constructor is ever called.

Comment: @SeanLynch: Yes, it's not a good idea to put mutable objects on the prototype, like [e.g. given arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4425318/1048572). But it's exactly what the question asked for: to be shared. If that is what you need, then it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`static`](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties#part-2-class-static-properties) to have class properties.

```
class MyClass {
  static myStaticProp = 42;

  constructor() {
    console.log(MyClass.myStaticProp); // Prints '42'
  }
}
```

N.B: this is a feature already implemented in [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), but is **still experimental** as only at the 1st proposal stage.

Comment: As I understand it, `static` is only for member functions not data.

Comment: But in my case I'd have to initialize `myStaticProp` with the arguments to the constructor.

Comment: @SeanLynch you can initialize to null and, in the constructor, have an `if (this.myStaticProp === null) { ... }`

Comment: @SeanLynch your understanding is incorrect, otherwise `Object.defineProperties(MyClass, ...)` would behave much differently.

Comment: OP asked for ES6 solutions