# ES6 - declare a prototype property in a class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am using ES6 classes. I want to achieve this.

```
function Grid(color) {
  this.color = color;
};

Grid.prototype.indexes = [];
```

I want to set indexes as a property of protoype object. How to achieve this in ES6 classes?

```
class Grid {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
    };
}
```

**Edit**:
Is there any other alternative than below mentioned solution?

```
class Grid {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
    };
}

Grid.prototype.indexes = [];
```

**Disclaimer**: I am completely new to javascript.

Comment: add ```this.indexes = [];``` inside the constructor.

Comment: You can copy the last line from your first example and paste it after `class Grid {...}` [Javascript ES6 shared class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922109/javascript-es6-shared-class-variable)

Comment: @SajeebAhamed It would add indexes to the class, and not to the prototype right?

Comment: @jefe23984 Sajeeb's approach would add indexes to each instance. And this is usually what you want to because having array in prototype potentially creates a lot of problems with shared mutable state. If you insist on sharing the array I'd recommend to put it in the class itself (using `static` keyword) so it won't look like an instance property.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, try to avoid attempting to mimic patterns that you are accustomed to from other languages. JavaScript is a rare breed.

Comment: Thnx!! @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Yeah. If you something like prototyping then extend the class and add new functionalities into the child class.

Comment: You need to do something like - class Grid {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
    };
   indexes = []
}

Comment: @Vishal Can you help me understand on how it will be shared among instances (i.e same copy or different) and can i access indexes outside the class?

Comment: Yes you can use it outside the class using new operator. so someting like var greenGrid = new Grid('green')  and then access greenGrid.indexes