# Nodejs Calling the class multiple times

Tags: node.js, class

I have simple class like that;

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.datas = {}
    }

    set(key, data) {
        return this.datas[key] = data
    }

    get(key) {
        return this.datas[key]
    }
}

module.exports = Foo
```

I am adding some data to `datas` veriable first. But when I call same class in the next time, veriable is not saving like that;

```
const foo1 = Foo()
foo1.set('a',[1,2,3])
const foo2 = Foo()
var aData = foo2.get('a')
console.log(aData)
```

But data not getting. How can I fix it?

Comment: any reason not to use `foo1.get('a')`?

Comment: I'm planning to class class inside another file. Real problem is not exactly like that but same situation

Answer (score 1):

The datas property that you defined in the `Foo` class is not being saved between instances of the class, because it is defined inside the constructor function. This means that every time you create a new Foo object with `const foo = new Foo()`, a new datas property will be created for that object, and it will not be shared with other instances of the Foo class.

if you want to shared by all instances of the class.refer [Javascript ES6 shared class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922109/javascript-es6-shared-class-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your object into another class constructor,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-k3vqtp?file=index.js

or use global variable

```js
global.foo = new Foo();
global.foo.set('a', [1, 2, 3]);
```

or use package like [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) to inject the class

```ts
...
@injectable()
export default class A implements IA {
  private _foo!: Foo;
  public get foo(): Foo {
    return this._foo;
  }
  public set foo(v: Foo) {
    this._foo = v;
  }

  constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.Foo) foo: Foo,
  ) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
...
```

Due to the limited information from your question, here only list some options. You can look for the best way to fit your scenario.